# Visual Studio 2019 Publish is Treating Warnings As Errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In the Build properties of my project I have 'Treat warnings as errors' to None:

[image]

This works fine when building but when I try to publish to a local folder I'm getting 14 errors that should be warnings. Does anyone know how to disable treating warnings as errors when publishing in Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line to the `<PropertyGroup>` section of the .csproj file took care of the issue:

```
<CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>false</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

Explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview